# Problemas de manipulación de fechas para hacer "próximos eventos" en Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, date

Estoy haciendo un calendario de eventos y mostrando, con ayuda de **Carbon**, las fechas desde la más reciente a ocurrir a la más lejana con la funciona `diffForHumans()` de **Carbon**.

Creo saber exactamente cual es el problema pero quisiera un consejo de cual es la mejor forma de manejar las fechas.

En la base la guardo como `String`, ya que `Date` solo me guardaba el día y yo necesitaba el combo.

Pero claro al momento de traer los eventos y ordenarlos por "fecha" es un `String`

```
$eventos= Evento::orderBy('fecha','asc')->get();
```

está claro que eso no me lo ordenará de forma correcta. Porque ordena `String`. ¿Cómo soluciono esto?

> Maraton del Becario  /  10.09.2016 14:00
>   Maraton Carussi /  08.10.2016 15:00
>   Maraton de Bovril  /08.10.2016 09:51
>   Maraton de la Salud /  30.09.2016 16:00

Siendo hoy 30/09 las 12:00 deberia mostrar primero la Maraton de la salud, pero la muestra a lo último. Después si pareciera ordenado.

También me sucede que cuando utilizo la función `diffForHumans()` de **Carbon** me esta sumando 3 horas  (supongo que tiene que ver algo con el GTM). Entonces si faltan 4 horas me esta diciendo que falta 1 hora. Así lo utilizo:

```
@foreach($eventos as $evento)
            @if($evento->fecha >= Carbon\Carbon::now())
            <h5>
                <a href="#">
                    {{$evento->nombre}} . {{$evento->distancia}}<br>
                    {{ Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',$evento->fecha)->diffForHumans() }}
                    {{Carbon\Carbon::now()}}
                </a>

            </h5>
            @endif
    @endforeach
```

También puede estar pasando algún problema de conversión al crear la fecha con **Carbon** a partir del `String`.

Comment: La mejor forma será almacenarlos como lo que son en la base de datos: Fechas y horas.

Comment: La primer parte la logre hacer andar con datetime pero la segunda parte me esta complicando. El carbon::now() y el diffForHumans() me estan sumando 3 horas. Lo cual me esta dando mal las diferencias. Ahi edito para mostrar como me quedo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cambiar la zona horaria debería solucionar el problema con el desfase de horas, usando el método `setTimezone('America/New York')` por ejemplo, teniendo en cuenta que diffForHumans() lo tiene en cuenta:

```
public function diffForHumans(Carbon $other = null, $absolute = false, $short = false)
{
    $isNow = $other === null;
    if ($isNow) {
        $other = static::now($this->getTimezone());
    }
    $diffInterval = $this->diff($other);
    switch (true) {
        case ($diffInterval->y > 0):
            $unit = $short ? 'y' : 'year';
            $count = $diffInterval->y;
            break;
        case ($diffInterval->m > 0):
            $unit = $short ? 'm' : 'month';
            $count = $diffInterval->m;
            break;
        case ($diffInterval->d > 0):
            $unit = $short ? 'd' : 'day';
            $count = $diffInterval->d;
            if ($count >= static::DAYS_PER_WEEK) {
                $unit = $short ? 'w' : 'week';
                $count = (int) ($count / static::DAYS_PER_WEEK);
            }
            break;
        case ($diffInterval->h > 0):
            $unit = $short ? 'h' : 'hour';
            $count = $diffInterval->h;
            break;
        case ($diffInterval->i > 0):
            $unit = $short ? 'min' : 'minute';
            $count = $diffInterval->i;
            break;
        default:
            $count = $diffInterval->s;
            $unit = $short ? 's' : 'second';
            break;
    }
    if ($count === 0) {
        $count = 1;
    }
    $time = static::translator()->transChoice($unit, $count, array(':count' => $count));
    if ($absolute) {
        return $time;
    }
    $isFuture = $diffInterval->invert === 1;
    $transId = $isNow ? ($isFuture ? 'from_now' : 'ago') : ($isFuture ? 'after' : 'before');
    // Some langs have special pluralization for past and future tense.
    $tryKeyExists = $unit.'_'.$transId;
    if ($tryKeyExists !== static::translator()->transChoice($tryKeyExists, $count)) {
        $time = static::translator()->transChoice($tryKeyExists, $count, array(':count' => $count));
    }
    return static::translator()->trans($transId, array(':time' => $time));
}
```

Comment: Y donde y como coloco ese metodo?

Comment: y donde encuentro una lista de zona horaria. Osea como se que va entre entre las comillas

Comment: Apartir de esto googlee y encontre como cambiar el timezone.. esta en proyecto/config/app.php buscamos timezone y en mi caso que vivo en argentina puse 'timezone' => 'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires',//'UTC',